# Stop `update_post_meta` from working each time page refreshes?

Tags: post-meta

So my code I have here including `update_post_meta` makes it work when clicking a button I have although what I fail to find out is how I can prevent `update_post_meta` from working on each page refresh/visit because I have this button on a certain page.

This is the code:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit">
        <?php
        $post = array(
            'post_title'   => $column1,
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
        );

        $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $post, true);
        if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
                return get_error_codes();
            }
        }else{
            wp_insert_post($thisid);
            update_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_1223ewedwd3123', $column2);

        }
        ?> 

    </form>
```

Comment: You're also inserting the post every time the page loads. You need to do your processing inside if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ - it all seems a bit disjointed at the moment...

Comment: Could you please show an example? I know I do but I have no idea how I should otherwise combine `is_wp_error` with the submit it originally was an else(the else that is now in the if submit) but than I added the button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over it again, it seems as though you're inserting the post twice. wp_insert_post returns the following (from the codex):

> The ID of the post if the post is successfully added to the database. On failure, it returns 0 if $wp_error is set to false, or a WP_Error object if $wp_error is set to true.

So you want to check that there's an error on $thisid if the form was submitted:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit" name="submit">
    <?php
    // if post submit is set
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // setup the post parameters, best not to call this $post
        // as that may interfere with the global $post var in WP
        $postargs = array(
            'post_title'   => $column1,
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
        );

        // attempt to insert the post
        $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $postargs, true);

        // if there was an error, return the codes
        if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
            return get_error_codes();
        // if not, update the meta
        } else {  
            update_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_1223ewedwd3123', $column2);
        }
    }
    ?> 

</form>
```

Also, it looks as though you're updating an ACF field? If so, you should use their update function over update_post_meta. Their update function will make sure to format the data correctly depending on the field type:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/